# Elemento sobrepondo o outro CSS

Tags: html, css, material-design

Meu site é composto por um `header` e abaixo dele um `container-fluid` com as informações da tela. 
O problema é que o meu `header` está sobrepondo parte do meu `container-fluid`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML:**

```
<h3 class="card-header primary-color white-text">Monitoramento</h3>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <form novalidate #f="ngForm">
    <div class="card">
    ...
```

**CSS:**

```
.card-header{
    height: 7%;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Pensei em adicionar um `margin-top: 7%` para dar a distancia exata entre um elemento e o outro, mas parece não ser suficiente, somente com `margin-top: 25%` é feito a distância correta entre os elementos, mas conforme vai aumentando a tela a distância vai se tornando muito grande e isso impacta o visual. 
Se eu tirar a `position: fixed` tudo funciona conforme esperado, mas eu preciso que esse titulo seja fixado ao topo.

Comment: Vc está usando algum framework tipo Materialize ou outro qualquer?

Comment: material design bootstrap

Comment: Seria esse? https://mdbootstrap.com/material-design-for-bootstrap/ ?

Comment: isso, esse mesmo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do *framework* que vc está usando https://mdbootstrap.com/ quando vc coloca `position:fixed` ou `position:sticky` na `NavBar` vc precisa colocar um `padding-top` no `body`

> Fixed navbars use `position: fixed`, meaning they’re pulled from the
>   normal flow of the DOM and may require custom CSS (e.g., `padding-top`
>   on the `<body>`) to prevent overlap with other elements.

Tradução: *"As barras de navegação fixas usam `position: fixed`, ou seja, são extraídas do fluxo normal do DOM e podem exigir CSS personalizado (por exemplo, `padding-top` no `<body>`) para evitar a sobreposição com outros elementos."*

**Fonte:** https://mdbootstrap.com/components/navbar/ *(ver em Placement)*

Comment: @Leticia obrigado! Esse tipo de problema é muito comum e acontece em outros frameworks tb tipo Bootstrap. A técnica mais comum para corrigir isso é a relatada na documentação com o padding-top no body. (o bootstrap tb indica fazer dessa maneira https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement )

Comment: Sim, eu utilizo o angular e não consigo definir css diretamente no body, não sei porque. Se eu definir body{padding-top: 60px} no styles.css ele não aplica no meu body.

Comment: Era para funcionar... vc pode tentar com `body{padding-top: 60px !important} ` mas pode ser que na compilação o angular remova os estilos do body... Vc pode inpecionar o body pelo DevTools do Browser e avaliar se o body está pegando algum estilo... Coloque um background-color no body tb para ver se é só o padding, ou se nem a cor de fundo ele está aceitando

Comment: eu acho que o angular remove automaticamente os estilos do body... não é a primeira vez que tento colocar diretamente algo no body :/

Comment: @Leticia Eu nunca trabalhei com angular, na verdade não entendo quase nada de JS. Mas talvez depois de executar o DOM vc pode adicionar alguma classe no Body... Se nada disso der certo acredito que um margint-top no header serja uma opção... ai se o conteúdo rolar por cima da nav é só vc colocar um z-index maior que o dos outros elemento que resolve. Esse ponto do Angular e classe no body infelizmente não sei resolver :/

Answer (score 1):

Olá eu não testei aqui mais você já pensou no z-index?Esse valor faz com que ele fique a frente dos outros elementos.

https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Para o titulo ficar fixo no topo basta um top:0